# Simple OpenGL application

Tags: c++, linux, opengl, g++

I am trying to learn OpenGL as a student. I spent a lot of time trying to figure out why this simple application is not working. It is an example of given by our professor. (We are working in windows with visual studio, but I have no choice but to use Linux at home, it is not a caprice). Here is the program that I wrote (On windows is working perfectly) and is just displaying a black windows (it is supposed to display a triangle).

```
//
//  main.cpp
//  OpenGL_Shader_Example_step1
//
//  Created by CGIS on 30/11/15.
//  Copyright © 2015 CGIS. All rights reserved.
//

#define GLEW_STATIC

#include <iostream>
#include "GL/glew.h"
#include "GLFW/glfw3.h"

#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>

int glWindowWidth = 640;
int glWindowHeight = 480;
int retina_width, retina_height;
GLFWwindow* glWindow = NULL;

GLuint shaderProgram;

GLfloat vertexCoordinates[] = {
                                0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f,
                                0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
                                -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f
                              };
GLuint verticesVBO;
GLuint triangleVAO;

void windowResizeCallback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height)
{
    fprintf(stdout, "window resized to width: %d , and height: %d\n", width, height);
    //TODO
}

void initObjects()
{
    //generate a unique ID corresponding to the verticesVBO
    glGenBuffers(1, &verticesVBO);
    //bind the verticesVBO buffer to the GL_ARRAY_BUFFER target,
    //any further buffer call made to GL_ARRAY_BUFFER will configure the
    //currently bound buffer, which is verticesVBO
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, verticesVBO);
    //copy data into the currently bound buffer, the first argument specify
    //the type of the buffer, the second argument specify the size (in bytes) of data,
    //the third argument is the actual data we want to send,
    //the last argument specify how should the graphic card manage the data
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertexCoordinates), vertexCoordinates, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    //generate a unique ID corresponding to the triangleVAO
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &triangleVAO);
    glBindVertexArray(triangleVAO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, verticesVBO);
    //set the vertex attributes pointers
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, NULL);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    //unbind the triangleVAO
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}

bool initOpenGLWindow()
{
    if (!glfwInit()) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: could not start GLFW3\n");
        return false;
    }

    //for Mac OS X
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 4);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 1);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

    glWindow = glfwCreateWindow(glWindowWidth, glWindowHeight, "OpenGL Shader Example", NULL, NULL);
    if (!glWindow) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: could not open window with GLFW3\n");
        glfwTerminate();
        return false;
    }

    glfwSetWindowSizeCallback(glWindow, windowResizeCallback);
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(glWindow);

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 4);

    // start GLEW extension handler
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    glewInit();

    // get version info
    const GLubyte* renderer = glGetString(GL_RENDERER); // get renderer string
    const GLubyte* version = glGetString(GL_VERSION); // version as a string
    printf("Renderer: %s\n", renderer);
    printf("OpenGL version supported %s\n", version);

    //for RETINA display
    glfwGetFramebufferSize(glWindow, &retina_width, &retina_height);

    return true;    
}

void renderScene()
{
    //clear the color and depth buffer before rendering the current frame
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    //specify the background color
    glClearColor(0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 1.0);
    //specify the viewport location and dimension
    glViewport (0, 0, retina_width, retina_height);

    //process the keyboard inputs
    if (glfwGetKey(glWindow, GLFW_KEY_A)) {
    //TODO
    }

    if (glfwGetKey(glWindow, GLFW_KEY_D)) {
    //TODO
    }

    //bind the shader program, any further rendering call
    //will use this shader program
    glUseProgram(shaderProgram);

    //bind the VAO
    glBindVertexArray(triangleVAO);
    //specify the type of primitive, the starting index and
    //the number of indices to be rendered
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
}

std::string readShaderFile(std::string fileName)
{
    std::ifstream shaderFile;
    std::string shaderString;

    //open shader file
    shaderFile.open(fileName.c_str());

    std::stringstream shaderStringStream;

    //read shader content into stream
    shaderStringStream << shaderFile.rdbuf();

    //close shader file
    shaderFile.close();

    //convert stream into GLchar array
    shaderString = shaderStringStream.str();
    return shaderString;
}

void shaderCompileLog(GLuint shaderId)
{
    GLint success;
    GLchar infoLog[512];

    //check compilation info
    glGetShaderiv(shaderId, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
    if (!success)
    {
        glGetShaderInfoLog(shaderId, 512, NULL, infoLog);
        std::cout << "Shader compilation error\n" << infoLog << std::endl;
    }
}

void shaderLinkLog(GLuint shaderProgramId)
{
    GLint success;
    GLchar infoLog[512];

    //check linking info
    glGetProgramiv(shaderProgramId, GL_LINK_STATUS, &success);
    if (!success) {
        glGetProgramInfoLog(shaderProgram, 512, NULL, infoLog);
        std::cout << "Shader linking error\n" << infoLog << std::endl;
    }
}

GLuint initBasicShader(std::string vertexShaderFileName, std::string fragmentShaderFileName)
{
    //read, parse and compile the vertex shader
 std::string v = readShaderFile(vertexShaderFileName);
 const GLchar* vertexShaderString = v.c_str();
 GLuint vertexShader;
 vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
 glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &vertexShaderString, NULL);
 glCompileShader(vertexShader);
 //check compilation status
 shaderCompileLog(vertexShader);

 //read, parse and compile the vertex shader
 std::string f = readShaderFile(fragmentShaderFileName);
 const GLchar* fragmentShaderString = f.c_str();
 GLuint fragmentShader;
 fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
 glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &fragmentShaderString, NULL);
 glCompileShader(fragmentShader);
 //check compilation status
 shaderCompileLog(fragmentShader);

 //attach and link the shader programs
 shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
 glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
 glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
 glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);
 glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
 glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);
 //check linking info
 shaderLinkLog(shaderProgram);

 return shaderProgram;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) 
{
    initOpenGLWindow();

    initObjects();

    shaderProgram = initBasicShader("shaders/shader.vert", "shaders/shader.frag");

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(glWindow)) {
        renderScene();

        glfwPollEvents();
        glfwSwapBuffers(glWindow);
    }

    //close GL context and any other GLFW resources
    glfwTerminate();

    return 0;
}
```

Here are the shader programs:
shader.frag:

```
#version 300 es
precision mediump float;

in vec3 colour;
out vec4 frag_colour;

void main() {
    frag_colour = vec4 (colour, 1.0);
}
```

and shader.vert:

```
#version 300 es

layout (location = 0) in vec3 vertex_position;

out vec3 colour;

void main() {
    colour = vec3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    gl_Position = vec4(vertex_position, 1.0);
}
```

and here is the command used to compile the program (I am using the visual studio code):

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "g++",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "args": ["-g",
             "-Wall",
             "-o", "lab2.exe", 
             "main.cpp", 
             "-I/usr/include/c++/4.8.5", 
             "-I/usr/include/GL", 
             "-I/usr/include/glm", 
             "-I/usr/local/include/GLFW", 
             "-L/usr/local/lib", "-lGLEW", "-lGLU", "-lglfw3", "-lGL", "-lm", "-ldl", "-lXrender", "-ldrm", 
             "-lXdamage", "-lX11-xcb", "-lxcb-glx", "-lxcb-dri2", "-lxcb-dri3", "-lxcb-present", "-lxcb-sync", "-lxshmfence", "-lXxf86vm",
             "-lXfixes", "-lXext", "-lX11", "-lpthread", "-lxcb", "-lXau", "-lXdmcp",
             "-lXrandr", "-lXi", "-lXxf86vm", "-lXcursor"],
    "showOutput": "always"
}
```

The args param is given to g++.
If I would have an error I would have a point from which to start but like this I don't know what to do.

Here is the result of the  `glxinfo | grep OpenGL` command:

```
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Haswell Mobile 
OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 11.2.0
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 3.30
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 11.2.0
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
```

Comment: Debugging help questions require a [mcve] as per the [help]. Your code is not minimal. Please [edit] your question to make sure that your code is Minimal (only the code necessary to reproduce your issue in your question), Complete (users do not need anything else to reproduce your issue), and Verifiable (the provided code does reproduce the exact issue you are facing). As it is your question is off-topic for Stack Overflow. Note that this is also a common [downvote reason](http://idownvotedyoubecause.com/so/TooMuchCode).

Comment: You don't seem to have an actual concrete question about programming. You may benefit more from just reading [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: you are asking for opengl 4.1 but driver supports only 3.3. I didn't check carefully if you are actually using anything requiring the newer version. But to check what goes wrong you want to use gl debugging or tracing to see what opengl/glx calls are failing. That will help figuring out what is actually the problem.

Comment: Furthermore, those shaders use `#version 300 ES`, which means OpenGL ES Shading Language, which is not guaranteed to be supproted in a GL 4.1 (or 3.3) context.

Comment: "application is not working"...Segfault?  Deleted your home directory?  Kernel oops?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using an opengl/glsl debugger to see what is going on. It's been a while but I had a lot of success using glslDevil previously - it's linux compatible and may help you spot an opengl error - particularly an unsupported feature on your hardware/platform.